# How to add QWidget to a QGLWidget

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qglwidget

What is currently the best way to add a QWidget to a QGLWidget as a child? In this case I want to add a QSlider to QGLWidget, however it seems like half the links on Google point to dead information now so it's tricky working out what the current way to achieve this is.

I did try creating a QSlider as a child and setting the geometry, but that didn't seem to do a lot.

Comment: Perhaps you've heard that `QGLWidget` is obsolete now, and that you should use [`QOpenGLWidget`](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/09/10/qt-weekly-19-qopenglwidget/) instead?

Comment: I hadn't actually, thanks. With the introduction of that new widget type, is there a new method for adding QWidgets as children?

Comment: I have not tried it, but as far as I know, it should work just by setting the parent. `QGLWidget` never supported adding child widgets properly, so you had to either paint them directly on the `QGLWidget` or put them in a `QGraphicsScene`. With `QOpenGLWidget` it should be possible though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Child widgets don't work with a `QGLWidget`, that's documented.

Use `QOpenGLWidget` and the child widgets will work fine. There's nothing special to do in this respect, simply add child widgets, layouts, etc., and it "just works".

Comment: That's great, thanks. Can you point to any code examples of `QOpenGLWidget`? I've tried doing an initial port of my 'QGLWidget` to it but run into various issues with segmentation faults, which I guess means I'm missing an initialiser somewhere but the documentation isn't clear on it.

Comment: Actually managed to convert it, not 100% certain how but I think I was relying on calls in the right place for the old format, and the wrong place for the new format. I created a new `QOpenGLWidget` and implemented base functionality to test, then reimplemented my functionality on top and all is well.